# How to extract integer from list with tuple in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to get a count from an ODBC database in Elixir.  I can see my result coming back, however, I don't know how to extract the value.

```elixir
{:ok, conn} = :odbc.connect('DSN=mydsn;UID=myuid;PWD=mypwd', [])
{:selected, _colNames, rows} = :odbc.sql_query(conn, 'select count(*) from mytable')
```

> {:selected, ['COUNT'], [{'182'}]}

**How do I get 182 out as an integer?**

The closest I got was getting the inner tuple:

```
hd(rows)
```

> {'182'}

Comment: I don't know if it would work for what you need but you might also want to look at Ecto: https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different possible solutions depending whether you are interested in this specific case or in a broader approach.

In this specific instance, as `rows` is expected to be a list with a single tuple with a single value, you can take advantage of the pattern matching to extract the value.

```
{:selected, _, [{count}]} = {:selected, ['COUNT'], [{'182'}]}
```

From this point `count` will match `'182'`. However, please note that `'182'` is different than `"182"`

```
"182" == '182'
false
```

As explained in the Elixir documentation, [`'182'` is a char-list](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#char-lists) whereas `"182"` is a String. Therefore you can't use [`String.to_integer`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/String.html#to_integer/1) directly as it will fail.

```
String.to_integer(count)
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer('182')
```

You first need to use `List.to_integer(count)` or alternatively convert it into a String, then cast to an integer.

```
List.to_integer(count)
182

String.to_integer(to_string(count))
182
```

This solution may not be applicable directly if the tuple contains more than one value (which means the query returns more than one value as result). However it's a starting point you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: You can use `List.to_integer(count)` to convert it directly from the list to integer.